# I cannot import a theme in wordpress on IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, xampp

Wordpress 6.0.1 is installed on IIS with PHP 7.4.30 and I'm using a plugin named All-In-One WP Migration to import a theme created on the same version but installed on XAMPP.

I want to move my wordpress theme created on XAMPP (PHP 7.4.29) to a IIS server (PHP 7.4.30), MySQL will stay on XAMPP.

**I'm using a plugin called All-In-One WP Migration to export the theme but when I want to import it doesn't work, it stays at 100% and in the browser console I see error 413 (Request Entity Too Large).**

If I import the theme on another XAMPP server this process of import works fine.

The reason I want to use IIS is because I have another asp.net website on it.

Screenshot :[image]

web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
   </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <security>
            <requestFiltering>          
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
        </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In php.ini I have configured these two values :

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
```

Comment: You have to let FRT tell what's wrong behind that 413 error, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing an older version of the plugin, link :

https://github.com/d0n601/All-In-One-WP-Migration-With-Import